# Supersized 3.0 - Stop Slideshow Loop?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Using Supersized 3.0 jquery plug-in and want slideshow to stop on the last slide. I have been at this for 6 hours. Any ideas?

I am new to javascript and jquery and this is probably something really simple that I am just not savvy enough to know. Please help, it will be greatly appreciated.

I did attempt to contact the plug-in's author and there is another person asking on his site but no answer for either of us. I am under a deadline to make this thing work so I am growing terribly concerned. I am an artist and trying to cross over into the code realm...but anyway, Thanks for reading this, have a good day, best regards, dawn

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like they've written in any kind of events for you to use.  So, you could either edit their code or do this funny hack.

```
var timeItTakesToGetToLastImageInMilliseconds = 6000;
setTimeout("$('#pauseplay').click()", timeItTakesToGetToLastImageInMilliseconds);
```

All it does is click the pause button for you after the right amount of time.  Good luck!